# Do browsers provide object oriented *element* Instances or a hierarchical tree structure or both?

Tags: javascript

I was curious to know how a browser exposes the elements within a Document Object model (DOM) to the Javascript developer. Does it create an *element* instance for each node in the DOM or does it expose a hierarchical tree structure that one must traverse to access *flat* elements ? If it provides a tree structure comprised of *element* instances why are the framework API's so divergent either exposing a procedural type of interface (e.g. jQuery/D3) or an object orientated one (e.g. Angular/React).

In Python, for instance, one may traverse the file system in two ways. Each are effectively equivalent but one is more procedural and the other is more object orientated.

- Using the `os` module - One may navigate the file system hierarchy by stepping through the folders to get to the files. The file, once found, is represented by a string and manipulated accordingly by means of string operations.
- Using the `pathlib` module - One navigates the file system hierarchy by calling a method on some root folder object. The file once found is itself an object and manipulated by calling various methods upon it. Underneath it's still manipulating a string but it's encapsulated away from the user.

Python 3.4/5 onward started allowing both methods to work interchangeably. That is one may generate a file object from a procedurally traversed tree or procedurally traverse a tree from some root object.

jQuery and D3 appear to work more like the `os` module traversing a tree structure and Angular/React work more like `pathlib` manipulating *element* instances. If the browser provided a hierarchy to work with then D3/jQuery would map directly to it while Angular/React must necessarily create *element* instances. If the browser provides *element* instances then D3/jQuery are flattening these elements into a tree structure that it navigates while Angular/React would map directly to these instances.

I suspect the real scenario is that the browser exposes a tree of *elements* and that jQuery/D3 choose to traverse it as a tree while Angular/React choose to work with the *elements* and ignore/hide the structure.

In a worse case scenario the browser might retain it's own *element*s exposing only a tree structure from which Angular/React then create their own *element* instances and vice versa for jQuery/D3 which flatten these instances into a tree.

Could one classify the Javascript frameworks like vue/ember/backbone as working predominantly like jQuery/D3 upon a tree or like Angular/React upon *element*s ?

Comment: Still not sure what "Does Javascript provide an Object Orientated Element Instance for one to manipulate ?" means by the end of that. The DOM API has instances of elements and tools to manipulate them… is the question about something else?

Comment: I suppose another way of asking this is "Is there a `Div` class that might be instantiated as a `div` object/instance ?", where `div` may be substituted for any HTML element. Does the browser provide such instances ? If one created their own representation/proxy instance for the one in the DOM are they doubling instances of a given `div` ? if so why not use the one maintained by the browser ? Sorry it's a weird question and I'm not sure I've worded it that well even after a few attempts.

Comment: Are you asking if you can say `var div = new HTMLDivElement();` in JavaScript? Answer is no.

Comment: I'm asking if the browser does `var div = new HTMLDivElement();` or some other equivalent (Proabbly in C++ or whatever) and if that is the case can one access the `div` instance from javascript ?

Comment: Of course you can... by getting a reference to it via the DOM APIs. That's what they're there for. As for what the browser does under the hood, *it doesn't and shouldn't matter*. As long as it conforms to the spec, it could be implemented in intercal or army ants or [rocks on sand](https://xkcd.com/505/) for all your code knows. I still don't understand what you're asking, and I'm trying to give you the benefit of the doubt by not e.g. downvoting, but I'm just not getting what you're after here.

Comment: HTML is parsed into the DOM, there's no mapping of nodes to HTML tags. To navigate the tree, there are parent and child and DOM query methods. There are also ["shadow DOMs" that may interact programmatically with the page DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM). I suspect the last is what you're looking for here.

Comment: @JaredSmith Jared Farrish sort of answered it, namely that the DOM isn't made up of tons of `TAG` instances for each tag in the HTML but rather that there is a single structure that is traversed, making the answer simply "no". (Funny XKCD btw) Should I delete the question ?

Comment: But the nodes of that tree structure are instances of various JavaScript classes, like [`HTMLDivElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDivElement).

Comment: There's an object instance for every element that gets parsed into the DOM, out of which you can interact with it through a given interface. There's no 1-1 relation between the text and the DOM. You can alter the DOM to include new elements that aren't part of the text plus the browser can add their own elements as well, nor does adding elements add their representation to a text file.

Comment: @Barmar and MinusFoure thanks, that answers my question. It seems `d3.selection(...).node()` is returning the [node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) element, or possibly some derivative.

Comment: Libraries like jQuery and D3 provide their own classes that hide the built-in DOM elements. I think `.node()` returns a D3 node object, not the underlying DOM node (but I could be wrong in this case, I can't actually find a `Node` class in the D3 documentation).

Comment: @Carel I'm glad they figured out what you needed. I wouldn't delete the question, but I'd reduce it to something terser now that you have a better idea of how to phrase it.